# How to get the record (by group) with max value? (Big Query)

Tags: google-bigquery

Consider the following data

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | t | 9 |
| A | d | 12 |
| A | l | 8 |
| B | x | 7 |
| B | z | 9 |
| B | q | 6 |

How do I extract the record with the max value in Col C for each value in Col A.

So the expected result would be...

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | d | 12 |
| B | z | 9 |

Trying

```
select ColA, max(ColC) from table group by ColA
```

doesn't provide the value in ColB.

I'm sure there is a simple and elegant solution here, but it's escaping me....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select * from your_table
qualify 1 = row_number() over(partition by colA order by colC desc)
```

if applied to sample data in y our question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

window function can be used here:

```sql
with tbl as (
Select  "A" as colA,    "t" as colB,    9 as colC
union all select "A","d",   12
union all select "A","dd",  12
union all select "A","l",   8
union all select "B","x",   7
union all select "B","z",   9
union all select "B","q",   6

)

select
colA,
max(colC),
any_Value(colB_max)
from (select *, first_value(colB) over (partition by colA order by colC desc) as colB_max from tbl )
group by 1
```

I added an entry for column A is "A". Then there are two entries for the max value of column C. The selected value for it from column B is more or less random.